# A fourth way of using "falloir"

Tags: registre-soutenu

There are three ways in which *falloir* can be used:

> 1. Il `falloir` + noun / Il + personal pronoun + `falloir` + noun.
> 2. Il `falloir` + infinitive (probably the most used form of *falloir*).
> 3. Il `falloir` que + subjonctive (when either the subjects in the main clause and the secondary clause are different or the language is
>      *soutenue*).

But recently I have noticed, especially in 19th century French, a fourth way in which *falloir* can be used:

> 4. Il + personal pronoun + `falloir` + infinitive.

Here are a few such *emplois*:

> Quand elle eut un enfant, *il **le** fallut **mettre en nourrice***.

---

> La musique du bal bourdonnait encore à ses oreilles, et elle faisait des efforts pour se tenir éveillée, afin de prolonger l'illusion de cette vie luxueuse qu'*il **lui** faudrait tout à l'heure **abandonner***.

---

> Elle se levait en sursaut; mais quelquefois *il **lui** fallait **attendre***, car Charles avait la manie de bavarder au coin du feu, et il n'en finissait pas.

---

> Or, comme il n'y a, de la Huchette à Buchy, pas d'autre chemin que celui d'Yonville, *il **lui** avait fallu **traverser*** le village, et Emma l'avait reconnu à la lueur des lanternes qui coupaient comme un éclair le crépuscule.

---

> Léon jura qu'*il **lui** fallait **retourner*** à son étude.

---

> Elle s'esquiva brusquement, se débarrassa de son costume, dit à Léon qu'*il **lui** fallait **s**'en **retourner***, et enfin resta seule à l'hôtel de Boulogne.

(All quotes are from *Madame Bovary*).

I don't understand the combination between the personal pronoun, usually in the dative case, and the immediately following form of *falloir*. When translated into English, it doesn't seem to make any sense at all.

Why is *falloir* used like this? And is this usage considered nowadays to be outdated?

Comment: Great question. I've been noticing lately that in other Romance languages, the order of object pronouns and the components of verb sequences is quite different from French. For example, in Spanish, you say, "Lo tengo que comprar," about the same as if French said "Je le dois acheter" (or even "Le je dois acheter"!). I'm pretty sure older French forms do more of that than newer French forms, but would need more familiarity with literature to dig up examples out of hand.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the forms you cite are literary.

The word order used in first one (*le falloir*) used to be the standard until the 18th century when the usage moved to the current one (*falloir le*).

> *Il **le fallut** mettre en nourrice* → *Il **fallut le** mettre en nourrice* (Sending **him** to wet nurses was necessary)

See this NGram:[image]

The remaining sentences do not use this archaic inversion but a different formal pattern: subject + pronoun + *falloir* + infinitive.

The pronoun (*me, te, lui, nous, vous, leur*) is an indirect objet representing who is required to do something. E.g.:

> *Il me faut partir.*

The usual way to express the same is:

> *Il faut que je parte.*

The second sentence moves also the verb at the end of the sentence while current usage would not do it :

> *qu'il lui faudrait tout à l'heure **abandonner*** → *qu'il lui faudrait **abandonner** tout à l'heure*

The remaining sentences follow the same formal pattern:

> *Il **lui fallait** attendre* → *il **fallait qu'elle** attende* (feminine here because *elle se levait en sursaut*)
>
> *Il fallait attendre* → "To wait was required"
>
> *Il **lui** fallait attendre* → "It was a requirement **for him** to wait"

This is different from the first sentence where *le* refers to the object (him) while here *lui* refers to the subject (for/to him). Note that this usage is not literary when *falloir* is followed by a noun, for example :

> *Il **lui fallait** une heure* = He/she needed one hour.

Compare to :

> *Il **fallait** une heure* = One hour was needed.

[Here](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/349.html) is an interesting reference from Jean-Michel Kalmbach about falloir usage .

Comment: Of course they are literary. They're from _Madame Bovary_. What did you mean by that? As to your example, _Il lui faut une heure_, that type of grammatical construction I understand. What I don't understand is what I call type 4, Il + personal pronoun + falloir + infinitive, which your example is not illustrative of because that would translate as Il + personal pronoun + falloir + noun [not infinitive].

Comment: @jlliagre Could you discuss the literary trend for your first example some more? Other instances of [subj + obj + verb + verb], where the object appears to belong to the second verb, if they come to mind?

Comment: I mean by literary that they are of a formal register and not expected in everyday's conversation. *Il lui fallait attendre* is very similar to *Il lui fallait une heure*, i.e. *She had to wait* here.

Comment: So, apparently, this old-fashioned word order was also the same in _aller + infinitive_, with the pronoun before "falloir" or "aller": "Félicité portait maintenant les robes de Madame; non pas toutes, car il en avait gardé quelques-unes, et _il les allait voir_ dans son cabinet de toilette, où il s'enfermait; elle était à peu près de sa taille, souvent Charles, en l'apercevant par derrière, était saisi d'une illusion, et s'écriait." (_Madame Bovary_) _Il les allait voir_ instead of _il allait les voir_. Same pattern, right?

Comment: @User26328 Exactly — I think that sort of structure was generally a feature of older/literary French!

Comment: @Luke and OP Yes, that's what the Ngram shows.

Comment: So, syntactically, these pronouns really belong to the infinitive verbs, and not to either _falloir_ or _aller_. Correct?

Comment: Yes, *il les allait voir* → *il allait les voir* → *il allait voir « eux »*

Comment: _Il le fallut mettre en nourrice → Il fallut le mettre en nourrice._  I am afraid your explanation works only for this first example. In the case of the other examples, it doesn't because all the other verbs are transitive, and yet the personal pronoun belonging to it is _lui_: _abandonner_, _attendre_, _traverser_ and _retourner_.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The remaining sentences do not indeed follow the same pattern. *Le* and *lui* are different beasts.

Comment: Another example, from the great La Fontaine: the third fable of his first book is _La Grenouille qui se voulait faire aussi grosse que le Bœuf_, nowadays often changed in _La Grenouille qui voulait se faire aussi grosse que le Bœuf_, as can be verified in several recent and even not so recent printings and adaptations of the fables.